# CloseEvent does not close a hidden main window

Tags: qt, show-hide, qsystemtrayicon

I have a `QMainWindow` that minimizes to the tray. In the tray I have two right mouse click menus. Show/Hide and Exit.

When the window is visible and I click to exit menu, the application closes correctly.

When the windows is not visible (hide), the application remains open.

The problem is not in the `MainWindow::CloseEvent()`. According to information from the debugger - the application correctly enters the `closeEvent` function, but it won't end.

Am I doing something wrong, is this a feature or a bug?
I tried putting `this->show()` first before exiting, but it had no effect on the result.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent)
, ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{

    ...

    /* try icon */
    trayIcon = new QSystemTrayIcon(this);
    trayIcon->setIcon(this->style()->standardIcon(QStyle::SP_ComputerIcon));
    trayIcon->setToolTip("Tray Program.\nWorking with minimizing the tray program.");
    menu = new QMenu(this);
    viewWindow = new QAction(("Maximize window"), this);
    quitAction = new QAction(("Exit"), this);
    connect(viewWindow, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(show()));
    connect(quitAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(closeFromTray()));
    closedFromTray = false;

    menu->addAction(viewWindow);
    menu->addAction(quitAction);

    trayIcon->setContextMenu(menu);
    trayIcon->show();

    connect(trayIcon, SIGNAL(activated(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason)), this, SLOT(iconActivated(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason)));

    ...
}
    
void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent * event)
{
    if(!closedFromTray)
    {
        this->hide();
        event->ignore();
    }
    else
    {
        event->accept();
    }
    QMainWindow::closeEvent(event);
}

void MainWindow::iconActivated(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason reason)
{
    switch (reason)
    {
        case QSystemTrayIcon::Trigger:
            if(!this->isVisible())
            {
                this->show();
            }
            else 
            {
                this->hide();
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
    
void MainWindow::closeFromTray()
{
    closedFromTray = true;
    close();
}
```

- Qt creator 11.0.2.
- Qt 6.5.2 with all latest updates.

How to terminate the application even when the window is hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [QGuiApplication::quitOnLastWindowClosed](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qguiapplication.html#quitOnLastWindowClosed-prop) with my emphasis:

> If this property is true, the applications quits when the last **visible** [primary window](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/application-windows.html#primary-and-secondary-windows) (i.e. top level window with no transient parent) is closed.". .

Use [`qApp->quit();`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcoreapplication.html#quit) instead of `close();`.

Answer (score 0):

I changed

```
void MainWindow::closeFromTray()
{
    closedFromTray = true;
    close();
}
```

to

```
void MainWindow::closeFromTray()
{
    QCoreApplication::quit();
}
```